# Join/ Merge 2 Comma Separated Text Files

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would really appreciate assistance in developing Python/ Pandas code to left-join 2 separate CSV files. I'm very new to Python so unclear how to begin. I have used Excel plugins to achieve same but it would normally hang or take hours to complete due to the huge amount of records being processed.

Scenario: joining on the first column.

CSV1

```
AN  DNM OCD TRI
1   343 5656    90
2   344 5657    91
3   345 5658    92
4   346 5659    93
```

CSV2

```
AN2 STATE   PLAN
4   3   19
3   2   35
7   3   19
8   3   19
```

Result inclusive of a match status if possible:

```
AN  DNM OCD TRI STATE   PLAN    Join Status
1   343 5656    90          No_match
2   344 5657    91          No_match
3   345 5658    92  2   35  Match
4   346 5659    93  3   19  Match
```

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html#pandas.merge) with `indicator=` parameter:

```py
out = df1.merge(
    df2, left_on="AN", right_on="AN2", indicator="Join Status", how="left"
)
out = out.drop(columns="AN2")
out["Join Status"] = out["Join Status"].map(
    {"left_only": "No_match", "both": "Match"}
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   AN  DNM   OCD  TRI  STATE  PLAN Join Status
0   1  343  5656   90    NaN   NaN    No_match
1   2  344  5657   91    NaN   NaN    No_match
2   3  345  5658   92    2.0  35.0       Match
3   4  346  5659   93    3.0  19.0       Match
```

Comment: Was pretty much thinking along the same line but with `df1.merge(df2, left_on='AN', right_on='AN2', how='left', indicator='Join Status').drop(columns='AN2').replace({'Join Status': {'left_only': 'No_match', 'both': 'match'}})`

Comment: Thank you! Trying to add a statement to only keep columns "AN" an and "DNM" as well as have the option to only have matched rows displayed. Can you assist w/ this?

Comment: @R.John You can do `print(out.loc[out["Join Status"].eq("Match"), ["AN", "DNM"]])` afterwards.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thanks! is there a way to output the results w/ only the selected columns? Tried this: `out.to_csv("result2.csv")` ... but all columns are being saved.

Comment: @R.John Try `out.loc[out["Join Status"].eq("Match"), ["AN", "DNM"]].to_csv("result2.csv", index=False)`

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have df1 and df2 and you want to merge the two dataframe

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='AN', right_on='AN2')
```

I hope this will help you